# I am a new to Oracle XE and Oracle . Help me to create my first DB

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I have installed  latest Oracle XE  on Windows 8.1 and Oracle Sql developer. Now I have some problem . My client has provided us one Remote Machine and I am using a VPN connection to access it . That machine  has Windows 2003 server and Oracle 11g or something installed . I want to copy a DB from that machine to my machine so that I can connect my local DB ( which should have all the Data and not just schema /*( They have provided DDLs but it creates only DB schema which i dont want )*/) . I am using ASP.NET 4.5 and VS 2013. I am totally new to Oracle . So my problem is how do I copy that DB on Remote to my Local .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use oracle's `exp` and `imp`for export and import, but you'll need server side access to the remote db. Another approach, as you have the DDLs allready and if you don't care about a true complete snapshot of the maybe changing remote db would be to copy each tables data i.e. via sqlplus:

`copy FROM user1/pwd@db1 TO user2/pwd@db2 INSERT targetTable  USING SELECT * FROM sourceTable;`

Though I must say, I'm not sure if this works for clob-columns. And if this is suitable surely depends on the amount of data you have to copy.

Comment: well I want something which we have in sql where I can easily get a .mdf file which has all data with tables schema's .. in Oracle , there is .dbf file .. so to be presize , is there any way with which I can have a .dbf file of DB hosted on Remote machine which I can copy and simply create a same DB on my local Machine and simply attach that .dbf file so a same replica of remote DB can be created .

Comment: No you can't simply copy the *dbf files. If you want to, you'll have to do a little research i.e. about Backuping and restoring Oracle-Databases (keyword: `RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE`) for example. In your case I would strongly recommend getting a dump-file via `exp`from the remote DBs dba and import it local with `imp`.

Comment: On remote machine , there is no server ,so i could not find exp.exe file :( besdies this , the db in question is huge ..only one table has 2.5 million records and there are 100 such tables .. so i have no idea how to copy all this